# Redis key matching performance

Tags: redis, sorl-thumbnail

We are using Redis for key-value ordinary caching and for our thumbnail cache. In a machine which has 100+ sites Redis thumnail database has 500000 keys without distinctive prefix like:

```
"sorl-thumbnail||image||6c4a67b016c4f867b9fdd3e5c5609887"
"sorl-thumbnail||image||ad7c56bd5461e9061604867d056b5de8"
"sorl-thumbnail||image||655ad6bb21129326ef4618df83a0f1f7"
"sorl-thumbnail||thumbnails||871641bfefa6250518fe52b86cf742c9"
"sorl-thumbnail||thumbnails||570565770557013bada8c1fe2cb3d658"
"sorl-thumbnail||image||c01134f4a8746d24c6d62543419bbb3a"
"sorl-thumbnail||image||ecc5afb281bc78fefe3046e2cc3f972a"
"sorl-thumbnail||image||670f1f1b6c5660f46053a484e22a4071"
```

Does using a prefix like 001,002,003,... 100 for site ids increase the performance  of accessing Redis?

Comment: Well, if you used a hash for each site instead of individual keys to store their thumbnails it would probably be more memory efficient, but other than that, as long as you know the key name we are still talking about O(1) time complexity (unless you use KEYS, which I hope you don't)

Comment: hi there, I'm using get and set for strings like:
GET "sorl-thumbnail||image||670f1f1b6c5660f46053a484e22a4071"

Comment: Ok, you'll see no difference in performance by using a prefix then.

Answer (score 4):

Because the data structure of the main dictionary is a hash table and not a tree, the general performance of Redis is not really impacted if you have plenty of keys with a common prefix.

Prefixing your keys with some discriminating data will not really improve performance.